# Garbage value long long data type

Tags: c

I need to calculate a large number which has length about 9-10 digits. Msdn says that long long type has a range for:
–9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

But when i run this code i get a garbage value printed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int seed = 88888; //This will be always a 5 digit number so the square of
                      // it will be 9 or 10 digits length
    long long square = seed * seed;
    printf("square = %lld", square);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
square = -688858048

Comment: a simple fix would be (if the seed is always positive) to use size_t rather than `long long`  Then printing it would be: `printf( "square = %lu\n", (unsigned long) square);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`seed` is of type `int`.  `seed*seed` will also be of type `int`.  And `88888*88888` overflows the size of `int`.  You then assign this garbage value to your `long long`.

Change the type of `seed`, or cast in you calculation:

```
long long square = ((long long) seed) * seed;
```

Comment: Oh god, what a dumb mistake. Thank you so much! I'll mark this as correct as soon as 8 mins pass

Comment: @TolgaŞen Don't forget that long long can overflow too if you use large enough values. The correct solution is to check if the multiplication is possible for the chosen type, before the actual computation.